# Average open bug life in days

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am looking to identify the average life time in days for open bugs based on severity.

| bug | severity | status | date_assigned |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | open | 2021-9-14 |
| 1 | A | in progress | 2021-9-15 |
| 1 | A | fixed | 2021-9-16 |
| 1 | A | verified | 2021-9-17 |
| 1 | A | closed | 2021-9-18 |
| 2 | B | opened | 2021-10-18 |
| 2 | B | in progress | 2021-10-19 |
| 2 | B | closed with fix | 2021-10-20 |
| 3 | C | open | 2021-11-20 |
| 3 | C | review | 2021-11-21 |
| 3 | C | close | 2021-11-22 |
| 4 | A | open | 2021-12-24 |
| 4 | A | closed | 2021-12-26 |

I would like to track no of days it takes for each of the severity (A, B, C, D) since their first status like (open/opened)  till their status changes to closed (close/ closed/ closed with fix)

This is what I tried so far,

```
select severity, count(distinct date_assigned) as no_of_days 
from Table 1 as a
join Table 1 as b
where status = 'open' | 'opened' and status = 'close' | 'closed' | 'closed with fix'
```

But this isn't giving me the expected output

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that there is one "open" and "close" per bug, then you can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select severity,
       avg( close_date - open_date ) as avg_days
from (select bug, severity, min(date_assigned) as open_date,
             max(date_assigned) as close_date
      from table1
      where status like '%open%' or
            status like '%closed%'
      group by bug, severity
     ) t1
group by severity
order by severity;
```

Note that date functions vary considerably among databases.  The exact syntax for the data difference may differ from above.

EDIT:

In Databricks, I think you want:

```
select severity,
       avg( datediff(close_date, open_date) ) as avg_days
```

Comment: Open is denoted as 'open' or 'opened' and likewise closed status is denoted as closed or close or 'closed with fix'

Comment: Should I just add the rest of the string in the like operator?

Comment: @Yash . . . The `like` logic should be whatever identifies opens and closes.  The above seems like a simple implementation.